# Virtualbox Ubuntu 17.04 cannot connect to the internet

Tags: networking, 17.04, virtualbox-networking

I upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 17.04 last two days ago. Ever since, I've been trying to connect to the internet, tried to change the 'bridged adapter' under setting > network. left at "NAT" ( as default option ); still didn't work. I tried a few things that I saw on Youtube, but still is not connecting to internet.

At some point, I noticed under "VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2" IPv4 was set to some random IP address within my subnet mask  (at least looked that way to me). I changed to DHCP hoping it would fix the issue. No luck.

At this point, I have feeling that if for some one who is familiar with VM than I am, it might be just a few clicks and fix the issue. I seemed to cannot figure that out.

Can someone shed some light on what should I do next please?

Comment: The "VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2" being changed should not matter much if you are using NAT/bridged network (which you should be if you are trying to access the internet from the VM). Try checking if your internet settings in the Ubuntu VM is correct (if it is set to DHCP instead of static, and if it is set to obtain DNS addresses correctly)

Comment: After I upgraded to 17.04, I don't remember changing anything myself, but while I was troubleshooting, I noticed it's changed back to some static IP twice, bit for DNS it was changed to static without any DNS address entered.  It's times I changed back to automatic, and DHCP. It's almost driving me crazy, all I wanted to do was to upgrade to 17.04, now I regret a little bit for upgrading it. I'm gonna check again a bit later today. I might post some screenshot as well. After see my next post, please let me know if you can make something of it. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @TimothyWong: I checked network settings. it's all check out. it's on obtain IP automatically; obtain DNS server information automatically.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had a similar issue.  I tried switching to bridged, etc, and nothing seemed to work.  Eventually I switched back to NAT, and found out which interfaces were available:

```
lshw -C network
```

I noticed that the networking was DISABLED.  Then I manually brought up the interface:

```
ifconfig enp0s17 up
```

But after that it still wouldn't work.  I had to manually get it to get an IP address using

```
dhclient enp0s17 -v
```

That did the trick and it's working now.  Not sure if this will help your issue, but it fixed mine.

Comment: You may need to use `sudo` to run the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Set your network settings in VirtualBox to look like this...

[image]

**Update #1:**

Change eth0 to enp0s3.

Comment: Thank you for your respond!! I went to setting>  network for so many times, I tried most of the options, still no luck. Also among all the options "eth0" was not an option I've ever seen in my virtual box. Except for some reason during the upgrade, my virtual box was really messed for some reason beyond my pay grade. I'll run "ifconfig" when I have access to my pc and post the screen shot here as well. Please have a look at all of my posts to see if it'll tell you where my vm's problem might be.

Comment: I didn't see that option, when I ran 'ifconfig', the following result came out: lo: flags=73<up,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> MTU 65536

Comment: I didn't see that option, when I ran 'ifconfig', the following result came out: lo: flags=73<up,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> MTU 65536  127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0 ; inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>; loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback) RX packets 372 bytes 27792 (27.7 KB); RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0; TX packets 372 bytes 27792 (2707; TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

Comment: Sorry, I was going to screenshot and post here. but didn't fee post picture option like you did. Also, it was around 6 lines of output, but didn't know how to post them here as they seem. Please try to understand and the output, and see if there is something wrong with it. Thank you a million

Comment: @DilAzat show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Edit your question with that output using copy/paste please. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have that info for me. ps: what version VB are you running? Did you install Guest Additions?

Comment: @heynnma: Thank you for your respond. I am not sure if I have installed guest addition or not, but while I had 16.04 LTS it was working without any issue. here is result of the command you sent me:

Comment: @testmachine: ~$ sudo lshw -C network

  *-network DISABLED
description: Ethernet interface
Product: 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE]
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
physical id: 3
bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
logical name: enp0s3
version: 40
serial: 08:00:27:13:78:d1
size: 100Mbit/s
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master ethernet physical tp mii 10bt-fb 100bt 100bt-fb autonegotiation configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=pcnet32 driverversion=1.35 duplex=hal
resources: irq:19 ioportLd020(size=32) memory:f0000000-f0000fff

Comment: Virtualbox Version: 5.1.26 r117224 (Qt5.6.2) ### I am sorry, website didn't allow me to add break line; had to enter separately. ( and that second post is all I got when I ran "sudo lshw -C network" , which looks very odd.

Comment: In the image from my answer, change the eth0 to enp0s3 and see if it all works for you now. Do you connect to the Internet via a wired connection, or a wireless connection? What other choices show in the eth0 pop up?

Comment: [1] Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7225
[2] Apple Mobile Device Ethernet #[This might be irrelavent, I don't why it's even an option]
[3] VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
[4] ASIX AX88772B USB2.0 Fast Ethernet Adapter

above are the options that I can select from. 
Under [Advanced] option:
I selected <PCnet-FAST III(Am79c973) 
my host is Windows 10; Guest is upgraded Ubuntu 17.04 from 16.04 LTS (  upgraded through upgrade manager, not using ISO file)

Comment: Since I am using virtualbox, it considers it as wired connection ?! but I am connecting my host machine ( Windows 10) wirelessly. Hope this can give you a better understanding about my PS's issue. Thank you very much

Comment: What are the choices under Advanced/Adapter Type?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 17.10 this solution worked for me to get 'NAT network' working. See this post: [Virtual NAT network NIC setup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399898/virtualbox-vm-cannot-connect-to-internet-through-nat)

Comment: Also this is easy setup, it worked like a charm without all the CLI stuff [NAT + Host-only](http://bertvv.github.io/notes-to-self/2015/09/29/virtualbox-networking-an-overview/)